# Can I strengthen my wrist and forearm while at the office?

Tags: wrist, forearm

I'm working out for 9 months by now, and was, until now, trying to lose weight.
Now that I'm pushing myself to weight lifting, I've found that I really need to strengthen my wrists and forearms.
When I tried to do some triceps exercises or some close-grip pull ups, I had some pain that is similar to tennis elbow.

Since I do work as a programmer at an office, is there something I can do to strenghten my wrists and forearms while at the office?

Comment: Yes, however - don't take golfer/tennis elbow lightly. It takes a long time to heal (it can take 2 years or even longer). Before trying to fix the wrong thing (might be your technique, might be overuse, anything, don't be sure it's your strength), please visit a doctor and drop everything that is causing that pain until then.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I strengthen my wrist and forearm while at the office?

Sure.

You can get these and use them whenever you feel like:

[image]

> When I tried to do some triceps exercises or some close-grip pull ups, I had some pain that is similar to tennis elbow.

That's not supposed to happen. Probably unrelated to grip strength. I'd suggest making sure your warm-up and technique are good, using lighter weights, and if the problem persists, consult a professional.

Comment: What are "these"? They look like dog chew toys...

Comment: @DarkHippo "hand grip rings" but they go by many different names